# Can I get Mac storyboards on Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I only have a 2007 macbook, and I can only get Xcode 4. I saw in Xcode 6 they have storyboards for mac (which I think was long overdue). Is there any way to get these mac storyboards in Xcode 4? (maybe port them in some how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get these mac storyboards in Xcode 4? (maybe port them in some how?)

**No.** There's no way to port Mac storyboards back to Xcode 4 because there's nothing to port them *to*. The problem isn't that Xcode 6 uses a different format or anything like that, it's that Xcode 4 doesn't support storyboards on the Mac at all.

Comment: Aahhhh… I guess ill need a new commuter then.

Comment: If you're using a 2007 Macbook for development, then yes, you need a new computer. On the bright side, if you can get 7 years of useful work out of a machine, you're doing pretty well.